# Loop over sentences to see if the sentence contains a trigger word

Tags: r

I have the following data-frame.

```
sentences <- c("this is app is great", "the price it too high")
df <- data.frame(sentences)
```

I would now like to run over each sentence in the data-frame to see whether a sentence contains a word from a list. I have the following lists set up:

```
product_names <- c("app", "mega").
marketing_names <- c("campaign", "marketing").
price_names <- c("price", "expensive").
```

I have written the following code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  list = strsplit(df$sentences, " ")
  for(l in list){
    if(l %in"% product_names){
      #Do something
      print(l) 
    }
    if(l %in"% marketing_names){
      #Do something

    }
    if(l %in"% price_names){
      #Do something
    }


  }

}
```

But this does not seem to work as I do not get a hit. I should get a hit on the first sentence. Any feedback on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How would your expected output look like?

Comment: I would like to have an additional column with the list whether there is a hit (0 = no, 1 = yes). And the name of the list is hits...

Comment: Can you update your post showing the expected output?

Comment: And if it hits multiple lists?

Answer (score 0):

Many small things.

The dataframe is interpreted as `levels` and not `character`, so it need conversion.

You try to split `df$sentences`, instead of `df$sentences[i]`, the current line.

Finally, `strsplit` returns a list with an array inside, so you need to first select the first element of the list to access the array of words.

Putting all together this lines becomes : `list = strsplit(as.character(df$sentences[i]), " ")[[1]]`

Finally, the `%in"%` should read `%in%`, so the final code reads :

```
sentences <- c("this is app is great", "the price it too high")
df <- data.frame(sentences)
product_names <- c("app", "mega")
marketing_names <- c("campaign", "marketing")
price_names <- c("price", "expensive")

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
  {
  list = strsplit(as.character(df$sentences[i]), " ")[[1]]
  for(l in list)
  {
    if(l %in% product_names)
    {
      #Do something
      print(paste(l,"found in product_names"))
    }
    if(l %in% marketing_names){

      print(paste(l,"found in marketing_names"))

    }
    if(l %in% price_names){
      print(paste(l,"found in price_names"))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Double loop, loop through sentences, then loop through name types for split words, see example:

```
df <- data.frame(sentences = c("this is app is great", "the price it too high"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


t(sapply(df$sentences, function(i){
  l <- unlist(strsplit(i, " "))
  sapply(list(product_names = c("app", "mega"),
              marketing_names = c("campaign", "marketing"),
              price_names = c("price", "expensive")), function(j){
                any(l %in% j)
              })
}))

#                       product_names marketing_names price_names
# this is app is great           TRUE           FALSE       FALSE
# the price it too high         FALSE           FALSE        TRUE
```